# Mysql first look value and then search with value find

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables :

Film :

```
id | title | year | Director
```

Casting :

```
id | title | year | actors
```

So What I am trying to do is to find all the actors that have the same title as the director.

So what I am trying to do first is

This will return me the film name.
And with the film name I want to do a second research to find all the actors that are in that film

So first :

Select title WHERE Director="name"

THEN Select Actor WHERE title="The first value I am looking for"

One example I am looking for Starwars movie.

My table information :

FILM

```
id:0 | title: "Starwars" | productor : "George Lucas"
```

Casting:

```
id:0 | title: "Starwars" | Acteur : "Ewan McGregor"

id:1 | title: "Starwars" | Acteur : "Natalie Portman"
```

So my MySQL should return only the name actors

```
Acteur : "Ewan McGregor", "Natalie Portman"
```

Thanks a lot of your help!

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE +INSERT INTO, and desired output for this data.

Comment: How would you exclude American Graffiti or would you not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using simple query as :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Casting.actors SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM Film
JOIN Casting ON Film.title = Casting.title
WHERE Film.Director = 'director_name'
AND Film.title = 'film_title';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(casting.actor) actors
FROM casting
JOIN film USING (title)
WHERE film.director = 'George Lucas'
GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: I'm baffled by the question - I know Lucas has other film credits than starwars but op only seems to want starwars in which case driving from film to find director would make more sense.